# How to retrieve the lm() coefficient more easily

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

In `dplyr` , using `group_map` can generate lm() models and combine the coefficient in a dataframe.
I want to add group information and Adjusted_R_squared to the final data.fame.

Currently I key in the value as vector and add to the data.frame. Is the any convenient way for this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

models <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_map(~ broom::tidy(lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length,data=.x))) %>% 
  rbindlist()
    
models$Species <- c('setosa','setosa','versicolor','versicolor','virginica','virginica')
models$Adjusted_R_squared <- c('0.05204','0.05204','0.5596','0.5596','0.7416','0.7416')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break out into a function within your `group_map()` you can customize your output a little more. Something like this:

```r
models <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(spe, spe_name) {
      results <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = spe)
      broom::tidy(results) %>%
        mutate(Species = spe_name$Species, Adjusted_R_squared = summary(results)$adj.r.squared)
    }
  ) %>% 
  rbindlist()
```

Comment: This is grate, function(spe, spe_name) need input 'spe' and 'spe_name' ,but i am little confused that where is 'spe_name' come frome ? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to run the function separately? You shouldn't need the input for `spe` and `spe_name`. Those are just the argument names for the groups and group names that are defined by `group_by(Species)`. 
If you read the help file for `group_map()` you'll see the details for why we need to define `spe_name` as well.